# Pass multiple functions to purrr:map

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I would like to pass multiple functions at once to one purrr::map call, where the functions need some arguments. As pseudo code:

```
funs <- c(median, mean)

mtcars %>% 
  purrr::map(funs, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This code does *not* run, but is intended to show what I am looking for: passing over multiple functions to `map` along with some arguments.

I looked at `compose` but that function does something different.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`invoke()` and its map variants have been retired in favour of `rlang::exec()`.  From the documentation:

> These functions are retired in favour of exec(). They are no longer
>   under active development but we will maintain them in the package
>   indefinitely.
>
> invoke() is retired in favour of the simpler exec() function
>   reexported from rlang. exec() evaluates a function call built from its
>   inputs and supports tidy dots
>
> invoke_map() is retired without replacement because it is more
>   complex to understand than the corresponding code using map(), map2()
>   and exec()

So the equivalent method now is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

funs <- c(mean = mean, median = median)
args <- list(na.rm = TRUE, trim = .1) # trim argument non-matching and ignored for median

mtcars %>%
  map_df(~ funs %>%
           map(exec, .x, !!!args), .id = "var")

# A tibble: 11 x 3
   var      mean median
   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 mpg    19.7    19.2 
 2 cyl     6.23    6   
 3 disp  223.    196.  
 4 hp    141.    123   
 5 drat    3.58    3.70
 6 wt      3.15    3.32
 7 qsec   17.8    17.7 
 8 vs      0.423   0   
 9 am      0.385   0   
10 gear    3.62    4   
11 carb    2.65    2
```

Comment: In the args list (`args <- list(na.rm...`), are all of those arguments passed to *all* of the functions? In other words, your function calls would look like: 

`mean(mpg, na.rm = TRUE, trim = .1)`

`median(mpg, na.rm = TRUE, trim = .1)`

`median(cyl, na.rm = TRUE, trim = .1)` `...`

Comment: Yes, all arguments are passed to all functions - probably not the best example given `trim` is not an argument for `median()` but in this case it's ignored.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to specify which arguments are passed to each function?

Comment: Yes - use `map2()` in place of `map()` and iterate over the list of functions and list of arguments in parallel.  Feel free to post a new question if you need help.

Answer (score 18):

You want to apply multiple functions to a dataframe with map(), but (apparently) there is no map() variation that does exactly this, only parts of it. For the multiple function part we have invoke_map() and for the multiple argument part over a dataframe we have pmap().

`invoke_map()` allows the use of multiple functions at once. For example, if we want to generate 5 random variates for a uniform and normal distributions, the code is:

```
func <- list(runif, rnorm) 
invoke_map(func, n = 5)
```

`pmap()` is just like map, but it allows to pass multiple arguments to a single function. For example, if we want to generate 10 random variates from a normal distribution with mean = 0 and sd = 1, but also 100 random variates from a normal distribution with mean = 100 and sd = 20, the code looks like this:

```
args <- list(mean = c(0, 100), sd = c(1, 20), n = c(10, 100))
pmap(args, rnorm)
```

To solve your question, we have to combine both functions in the following way:

```
fun <- function(f) pmap(list(x = mtcars, na.rm = TRUE), f)
param <- list(list(mean), list(median))

invoke_map(.f = fun, .x = param)
```

How does this work?

1. At the invoke_map() level, `fun` takes as arguments `param`, which are the functions we want to apply to `mtcars`.
2. Next, at the `fun` level, these functions stored in `param` are applied by `pmap()`, one at a time, to each column in `mtcars`.

*Note: For the solution to really make sense, keep in mind the arguments invoke_map() and pmap() take.*

More info about how [invoke_map()](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/invoke.html) and [pmap()](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) work.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I wished the solution was more straightforward, though. The code is not easy to read.

Comment: maybe this code is clearer: 
`mtcars %>% purrr::map_dfr(mosaic::favstats)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is my baby-steps solution (depends what you mean by "at once"):

```
mtcars %>% 
  map_dbl(~{mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)}) %>% 
  enframe() %>%
  rename(mean = value) %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  left_join(mtcars %>% 
              map_dbl(~{median(.x, na.rm = TRUE)}) %>% 
              enframe() %>% 
              as_tibble %>%
              rename(median = value))
```

Comment: That's a valid way, although I would have hoped for something more straight forward. Thanks!