# Pass multiple functions (each one time) ussing purrr

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr

I have a folder with different files, each with a different format, so I created different functions able to read each of the files. Is it possible to use `map` to apply the corresponding function to the corresponding file?

I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415072/pass-multiple-functions-to-purrrmap) to apply several functions to the object, but I don't think is applicable in this case since here all functions are applied always.

```
all_files <- list.dirs(file.path(path))
fun_A <- function(x) {read.csv(x)}
fun_B <- function(x) {read.table(x)}
fun_C <- function(x) {read.delim(x)}

funs <- c(fun_A , fun_B , fun_C)
```

So, if I do it manually it works:

```
(all_files %>% 
    purrr::map(., ~list.files(., full.names = T)))[[1]][1] %>% fun_A() %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows((all_files %>% 
                      purrr::map(., ~list.files(., full.names = T)))[[1]][2] %>% fun_B ()) %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows((all_files %>% 
                      purrr::map(., ~list.files(., full.names = T)))[[1]][3] %>% fun_C())
```

But I tried several times with `purrr` and I am not able to make it work. This is my final attempt:

```
 all_files %>%  purrr::map(.x = ., ~{
    df = (.x)
    funs %>% purrr::map(., ~ df %>% (.))
    })
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: is it not possible to determine the file type based on the file extension and then use the appropriate function to read it in?

Comment: Here I simplified the example, but in my real scenario, each file requires some data manipulation before being combined as rename, reformatting dates, etc... so I cannot use `fread` or use the file extension as index

Comment: If you want to read corresponding file with corresponding function, then you may need `map2` instead of `map`

Comment: @akrun, if I use `map2` and assign functions to `.f`, what do I pass to `.y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Map` or `map2` as suggested by @akrun

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) y(x), all_files, funs))
```

Using `map2_df` :

```
purrr::map2_df(all_files, funs, ~.y(.x))
```

For this to work it is expected that `length(all_files)` and `length(funs)` are equal.